# throw something in display google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm doing a script for a gadget to a site in google sites platform, shows an accurate information on the screen but I can not use method MsgBox (), which method should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Dialog Box widget](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_dialogbox) . You cannot use MsgBox() outside of Spreadsheets.